# Android: Show custom UI View in Eclipse layout viewer

Tags: android, eclipse, view

Does anyone know how I can get my custom view object to appear in Eclipse's Android layout tool when I put the parameters in my layout file?

If you don't want to put any code here, just a link to a resource would be great too. I'm not having any luck searching for what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your view displayed in the Layout View in Eclipse is not straight forward. From what I've seen (it's not exhaustive at all), using a completely custom View / Surface View with the rendering placed in a separete thread does not work.

But if you're building a custom View based on an existing one (for example inheriting from an EditTExt) and only overriding the onDraw method, then the layout manager will display your view as intended. The the parameters inherited from the Android View (here EditText) will apply to your custom View. Custom parameters won't have effects (I think).